# How can I update rows of DataTable(bokeh DataTable)

Tags: python, dataframe, bokeh

I want to change the number of rows of DataTable in Bokeh.
I have the DataFrame and resample it by someperiod, for example daily and monthly.
So I used below.

```
period_list = ["hour", "day", "week", "month", "year"]
period_select = Select(title="test", value="day", options=period_list)

def update_graph(attrname, old, new):
    table_source = <resampling code>
    DataTable.source = table_source

period_select.on_change('value', update_graph)
```

I expect the number of rows is changed,
but the number of rows of DataTable is not changed.

Initially, the DataTable shows 2 rows(sum of each days in 2 days).
When I choose "hour", I want it shows 48 rows, but it just shows first 2.
How can I change the number of rows?